# How to Sort array string by different point in the string

Tags: php

I have this as result in and HTML page created from script.

```
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_3924.html", "thumbs/IMG_3924.jpg", 150, 100, "IMG_3924.jpg", "slides/IMG_3924.jpg", 150, 100, "", "sorting01", 0)
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_3909.html", "thumbs/IMG_3909.jpg", 100, 150, "IMG_3909.jpg", "slides/IMG_3909.jpg", 100, 150, "", "sorting02", 0)
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_3914.html", "thumbs/IMG_3914.jpg", 150, 100, "IMG_3914.jpg", "slides/IMG_3914.jpg", 150, 100, "", "sorting02", 0)
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_3904.html", "thumbs/IMG_3904.jpg", 100, 150, "IMG_3904.jpg", "slides/IMG_3904.jpg", 100, 150, "", "sorting01", 0)
```

And here's the code that produced it

```
if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != ".." && strpos($file2,'.')!==0 ) {
  list($widthT2, $heightT2, $type2, $attr2) = getimagesize($pathToThumbs."/$name2.jpg"); 
  $thumbW2 = $widthT2;
  $thumbH2 = $heightT2;
  $out[]="thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, \"slides/$name2.html\", \"thumbs/$name2.jpg\", $thumbW2, $thumbH2, \"$name2.jpg\", \"slides/$name2.jpg\", $widthT2, $heightT2, \"\", \"$commentaire\", 0)\n";
}

}

//usort($out, function ($a, $b){
//    return substr($b, -8) - substr($a, -8);
//});
sort($out);

foreach($out as $key => $value){
  print $value;
}
```

How can I sort the results so they are sorted by `sorting01`, and then by `sorting02` text at the end of each line? I want to sort the array from what the last 2 fields of each line contains.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Refer to http://sscce.org/ for how to keep your code snippet clear. Currently, `sorting01` and `sorting02` are not defined. Where are you getting them from?

Comment: Hi, yes they are in the results. the $out[] give me the results you see upthere, but I want to sort those result by a specific point in the result. I don't want to sort them alphabetically from left to right, but from position 140 on this thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_3924.html", "thumbs/IMG_3924.jpg", 150, 100, "IMG_3924.jpg", "slides/IMG_3924.jpg", 150, 100, "", "sorting01", 0)

Comment: Maybe to be more clear, I want to sort the array from what the last 2 "" contains. on each lines

Comment: Ah, I see. The example runs off the right end of the screen and I didn't notice them. To be clear you should edit your question and say, "I want to sort the array on the last two fields."

Comment: Ok, I changed it. Any idea how please?

Comment: check out `array_multisort`: http://php.net/array_multisort

Comment: Your question is still very unclear. Which field should take precedence? One of your indicated fields you're intentionally overwriting to be "", so sorting on that field is useless. When you say 'sorted by sorting01 then by sorting02' are you saying 'sort alphanumerically'? Or something else?

Comment: yes alpha. My script is doing a while to put everything in the array. As you can see, the results of that script is upthere. All the lines have img in it. So now they are sorted by IMG be cause the usort read from left to right to sort them. But I want to sort those lines by what's inside the 2 "" at the end of each line. Cause what are inside those 2 "" are like categories of those pictures. Like wedding, portrait, etc.. tks

Comment: I want to sort them by $commentaire. Maybe easier to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching last `"some text in quotas"` in strings and compare:

```
function compare($a,$b) 
{
    // searching commentaire (searching last " and second from end ")

    $end_commentaire = strrpos($a, '"');
    $substr_a = substr($a, 0, $end_commentaire);
    $begin_commentaire = strrpos($substr_a, '"');   
    $substr_a = substr($substr_a, $begin_commentaire+1);

    $end_commentaire = strrpos($b, '"');
    $substr_b = substr($b, 0, $end_commentaire);
    $begin_commentaire = strrpos($substr_b, '"');   
    $substr_b = substr($substr_b, $begin_commentaire+1);

    //echo "|$substr_a|$substr_b|<br>";

    // compare 

    $result = strcmp($substr_a, $substr_b);

    // $substr_a and $substr_b are different,
    // don't compare rest of string 

    if( $result != 0 )
         return $result;

    // $substr_a and $substr_b are the same,
    // compare rest of string 

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($out, 'compare');
```

Put this in place of `sort($out)`

**Edit:**

Using RegEx:

```
function compare($a,$b) 
{
    // searching commentaire (searching last " and second from end ")

    preg_match('/"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/', $a, $result_a);
    preg_match('/"([^"]*)"[^"]*$/', $b, $result_b);

    //echo "|$result_a[1]|$result_b[1]|$result_a[0]|$result_b[0]|<br>";

    // compare 

    $result =  strcmp($result_a[1], $result_b[1]);

    // $result_a[1] and $result_b[1] are different,
    // don't compare rest of string 

    if( $result != 0 )
         return $result;

    // $result_a[1] and $result_b[1] are the same,
    // compare rest of string 

    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($out, 'compare');
```

Comment: Tks, but the problem is that it's not always the same results. Somethimes it's longer $commentaire. So how can I tell to look only in the last 2 ""?

Comment: let say I have those as results
"slides/IMG_3924.jpg", 150, 100, "", "Wedding", 0)--------
"slides/IMG_3925.jpg", 150, 100, "", "Portrait", 0)--------
"slides/IMG_3926.jpg", 150, 100, "", "Landscape", 0)--------
"slides/IMG_3927.jpg", 150, 100, "", "Wedding", 0)--------
"slides/IMG_3928.jpg", 150, 100, "", "Wedding", 0)--------
So I want all my weddings and all other together

Comment: Ok tks furas. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Done. I seach last " and cut all after " , than I search last " in new (sub)string and cut all before " .

Comment: Hi furas, one thing is missing for me, if possible. Now that we have sorted the categories, we need to sort after that the photo names alphabetically also inside the category. Is it possible?

Comment: I think that if I add a sort($out); after the usort($out, 'compare'); that will do the trick. what do you think? Or maybe not finally. ... lol. tks for another idea.

Comment: I think that `sort($out)` (in some situations) can mess up all. I change my code in the moment.

Comment: Done. If two lines have different `$commentaire` you don't have to compare rest of strings because it can mess up order.

Comment: thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_4341.html", "thumbs/IMG_4341.jpg", 150, 100, "IMG_4341.jpg", "slides/IMG_4341.jpg", 150, 100, "", "05-Couple", 0)    
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_9912.html", "thumbs/IMG_9912.jpg", 150, 100, "IMG_9912.jpg", "slides/IMG_9912.jpg", 150, 100, "", "03-Ceremonie", 0) 
thumbnail[++nr] = new makeIt(nr, "slides/IMG_9985.html", "thumbs/IMG_9985.jpg", 100, 150, "IMG_9985.jpg", "slides/IMG_9985.jpg", 100, 150, "", "05-Couple", 0)    
As you can see, 05-Couple has been splitter by 03-Ceremonie

Comment: your code ... the function top one. I don't know if it's because there's a big gap between pictures number.. But I guess not

Comment: Wait, I think i've made a mistake... let me try again... Mabe m ftp did not save it correctly.

Comment: Yep, finally, it was me Sir the problem.. Your code is fine and working perfectly. Nice to meet you and wish you a GREAT day.. See ya. Seby